# Props undefined inside the return but otherwise defined

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to pass some props from the parent to the child component but I am very confused. When I try to print the props before the return I get the values but if I try to used them in the jsx I get undefined.

```
const FormField = (empty, stateName, value, smallLetters, changeValue) => {
   console.log(empty, stateName, value, smallLetters, changeValue);
  return(
    <div>
      {console.log(empty, stateName, value, smallLetters, changeValue)}
  <label htmlFor="formGroupExampleInput">{value}</label>
   <input type="text" className='form-control' required onChange={(e) => { changeValue(e, stateName); }}/>
  </div>
);
}
```

Result from the print statements: [image]

Answer (score 1):

A react function component expects `props` as an object, not as individual arguments.

Try

`const FormField = ({empty, stateName, value, smallLetters, changeValue}) ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Your functional component can accept props property as an argument in () - brackets, you can then destructure it like this

without destructuring - `const FormField = (props)` and then access your props in the render byusing props.empty, props stateName etc

with destructuring  `const FormField = ({empty, stateName, value, smallLetters, changeValue})`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
const FormField = (state) => {
  const propsNow = state;
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(propsNow.empty)}
      <label htmlFor="formGroupExampleInput">{propsNow.value}</label>
      <input type="text" className='form-control' required onChange={(e) => { propsNow.changeValue(e, propsNow.stateName); }}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: It is not `state`, as you know it is `props`. Though this is just a name it would be proper to use the convenient names. Also, why do need to reassign it to another variable? Just use it as it is or destruct the needed props as other people suggested.